# `MVC` How to change the value of a piece of text on a View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm coming from the perspective of someone who has been working with `Webforms`.

Now I understand the relationships of `Controllers` pulling from `Models` presenting into `Views`.

I'm currently playing around with `MVC`.

In `Webforms` we had a code-behind file for the front-end counterpart `.aspx` and `.aspx.cs`.

Say for the basic template of a new `MVC` project we have the `HomeController` and `Index.cshtml`.

Here's the outline of the scenario in my head of what I'm trying to do:

On the `Index.cshtml` I see there is a `ViewBag` (I'm using this as an example I know there's another(a few) ways of doing this better than bloating the `ViewBag`), setting the title to "Home Page".

Now for the `Index.cshtml` `View` The `Controller Action` for this is:

> HomeController.cs > Index()

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.PersonalName = "Bob";
    return View();
}
```

(I've added the `PersonalName` line into that method).

If I want to access a value I could do something like this on the front end to pull it out:

```
<div>@ViewBag.PersonalName</div>
```

Now this is where the `Webforms` is probably corrupting me here regarding my thought process.

In my mind I'm thinking event handlers for `OnButtonClick's` however that's apparently not how we do it anymore but the concept of that is what I'm trying to achieve, allow me to elaborate...

Say I have a button on `Index.cshtml` that when it's clicked sets the text from above (inside a `Div` tag) in this question to something entered into a `TextArea` of the `Index.cshtml` `View`.

How would I pass the user-entered `Text` from that `TextArea` and display it on the same `View`?

I'm sorry that this may have been an overkill question for this particular example but I'm trying to be as exact as possible.

Thank you.

EDIT 1: I do not wish to use `AJAX`

EDIT 2: I would like it to be done Server-Side if at all possible.

Comment: The answer probably is: JavaScript/JQuery (or any kind of client side programming)

Comment: @Steve would it be possible to do this Server-Side, though? Imagine if I wanted some basic validation I didn't want tampering with on the Client-Side.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You need to look at _Html.BeginForm_ or to _Html.ActionLink_  and how to call a controller's method  and the parameters to pass to the method from your .cshtml page.

Comment: If you want this text to change without POSTing to the server you will need to do this in JavaScript. Attach some event handler to your control in JS and when that event raises, call the function that changes the text. Otherwise you can accomplish this in code behind c#, add a button that is <runat=server> once pressed, DoSomething() and update your TextArea in C#. I also like to just add ID's to my ASPx controls and Ref them in code behind.

Comment: @ShadowBlade You're referring to `Webforms` I'm doing this in MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

and in your HttpPost action, use a parameter with same name as the textbox name.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Report(string name)
{

   //Do server validations here

   //set posted value in view bag
    ViewBag.PersonalName = name;
    return View("Index");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices : 
1) Make the TextArea into a form tag then on sumbit try to get the value and bind your view with this value using ViewBag or ViewData 
2) Use javascript to get value then bind the div with the value ( this solution is better than send request to controller )